# Putting ListenAndServe into goroutine

Tags: go

I'm having trouble to estimate if there will be side effects of running http.ListenAndServe in goroutine.

To make it possible for prometheus to collect stats data from a /metrics endpoint of a service running a kafkaclient(running a kafka consumer in an infinite for-loop)

```
var addr = flag.String("listen-address", ":8070", "The address to listen on for HTTP requests.")

func main() {

   flag.Parse()
   http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
   go http.ListenAndServe(*addr, nil)

   for {....}
```

What would be the best practices to start the monitoring endpoint and run the infinite loop?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with running http.ListenAndServe concurrently to something else. You can do both things: put ListenAndServe on its own goroutine or the Kafka consumer. It does not matter. But don't do it like you did as this swallows any error returned from ListenAndServe.

Comment: could you downvote guys explain why this question is so bad for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice is to check for and handle errors. The error from http.ListenAndServe is ignored.

If return from http.ListenAndServe is fatal to the application, then use the following code or some variation on it to handle the error.

```
go func() { 
     log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(*addr, nil)) 
}()
```

The call to log.Fatal logs the error and exits the application.

Comment: Not all errors are fatal - `http.ErrServerClosed`.  See example code [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_Server_Shutdown)

Comment: @colminator  Any return from http.ListenAndServe is fatal to the OP's application.

Comment: Yes. My comment merely shows that a http server can be spun and shutdown in a controlled fashion.